# spectral sequence for etale cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, etale-cohomology

I'm reading Etale cohomology. so I need to learn elementary spectral sequence for Leray spectral sequence. Please give me a reference so that I can quickly go to the main subject.

Comment: http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/download/etale-cohomology.pdf or http://www.math.mcgill.ca/goren/SeminarOnCohomology/etale2.pdf

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not demonstrate a serious research effort by the OP.

Answer (score 2):

The Leray spectral sequence is explained in McCleary, **A User's Guide to Spectral Sequences**.